# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib' in updating data

Tags: c#

i am currently completing an assignment which requires me to develop a program for a school's registration system. The system provides an update function and regardless which details i want to update, the exception will always occur. This is the code:

```
     public void updateData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Find Student");
        Console.Write("Student id: ");
        string code = Console.ReadLine();

        Studentdetails target = Data.getStudent(code);

        if (target == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Record not found!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + target.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Student status: " + target.status);
            Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + target.gender.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Standard: " + target.standard);
            Console.WriteLine("1.Classroom: " + target.classroom);
            Console.WriteLine("2.Reg payment status:" + target.studReg);
            Console.WriteLine("3.Annual payment status:" + target.annual);
            Console.WriteLine("4.Satu Keluarga Payment status:" +target.sk);
            Console.WriteLine("5.Monthly payments due: " + target.payment);

            Console.Write("Select details to update (numbers given): ");
            int choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Console.Write("\nNew classroom: ");
                target.classroom = Console.ReadLine();

            }

            if (choice == 2)
            {
                target.studReg = "Paid";

            }

            if (choice == 3)
            {
                target.annual = "Paid";


            }

            if (choice == 4)
            {
                target.sk = "Paid";
            }

            if (choice == 5)
            {
                int paid;
                Console.Write("\nTotal months just paid?: ");
                paid = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

                if (paid > target.payment)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid amount of payment");
                }

                else
                {

                    int lastpayment = target.payment;
                    int newpayment = lastpayment - paid;
                    target.payment = newpayment;


                }
            }

            student_list[target.id] = target;


        }
```

So how did my index gets out of range/in a negative value/out of collection size?

Comment: inspect this line: `student_list[target.id]` most probably the index passed does not exists in list

Comment: Does `target` come from `student_list`? If so, you don't need to set it again, it is a reference type so the changes will appear there without setting the array value. It would help if you posted the `Data.getStudent()` method and where `student_list` is defined and initialized.

Comment: @RonBeyer `target` does not come from `student_list`, but im a bit unclear with your suggestion? can you elaborate it more?

Comment: @ShafiqNorhisham I can't elaborate without seeing more code about what `student_list` is and how `target` is assigned from the `Data.getStudent` function.

Comment: @RonBeyer oh sorry `student_list` is my `arraylist` in storing my data. For the `getStudent()` method

`public static Studentdetails getStudent(string code)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < student_list.Count; i++)
            {

                Studentdetails student = (Studentdetails)student_list[i];

                if (student.studid == code)
                {
                    student.id = 1;
                    return student;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }`

Comment: Right, `target` comes from `student_list`, so the line at the end: `student_list[target.id] = target;` can be removed entirely, the object will update because it is a reference type. You don't have to assign it back to the array as long as `StudentDetails` is a class and not a struct.